Prove that any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a regular value for $F$.
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function with $rank f = 1$ at all points. Define $F: TM \to \mathbb{R}$ as $F(X) = Xf$. ($X \in T_pM$ and $Xf$ is a directional derivative, am I right?). Prove that any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a regular value for $F$.
I have troubles with understanding the statement of the problem. Given $p \in F^{-1}(\{a\})$ we want to show that  $dF_p: T(TM) \to T\mathbb{R}$ is a surjection. I don't know how to go about $T(TM)$. I suspect I might be misunderstanding something.

@OrangeMushroom What do you mean by vertical subspace?

@OrangeMushroom Can you please tell me what do you mean by lifting $w$ into vertical subspace? I am not very fluent with these topics so I need more explanation.

You can show that $dF$ is always onto, and from this you see that every value is regular. Take any point $m\in M$, and pick coordinates around $m$. We have (sum over repeated indexes) $$ df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dx^i, $$ and because of the rank condition we can pick some $w\in T_mM$, say $$w=W^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},$$ such that $df(w)\neq 0$. Take now $v_m\in T_mM$, and standard tangent bundle coordinates in $TM$. We see that $F=v^i\partial_{x^i} f$ and, in particular $$
dF= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}dv^i+v^i\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} dx^j.$$ And now, the vector ${\rm ver}(s)\in T(TM)$ at $v_m$ given by $$ {\rm ver}(w)=W^i\frac{\partial}{\partial v^i} $$ is such that $dF({\rm ver}(w))=df(w)\neq 0$.
The intrinsic (coordinate free) construction of ${\rm ver}(w)$, as @Orangemushroom has pointed out in the comments, is to consider the so-called vertical lift of $w$. There are various ways to define it, but in any case it satisfies the following: for any form $\alpha$ in $M$, if we let $\overline{\alpha}$ denote the induced function on $TM$, then $\overline{\alpha}\big({\rm ver}(w)\big)=\alpha(w)$. In you notation $\overline{df}=F$.
